# Transition only for translate property

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, transform

I have two transform operations (rotate and translate) and I want to make transition for translate only (rotate have to be instant).

Some suggestions? I prefer pure css.

Comment: Provide us your code first.

Comment: Also decide on whether you want an animation or a transition...they are two different things.

Comment: you can't transition only translate but not rotate for the same element , I'd wrap the element in a div/span and apply translate to one and rotate to the other , that way you'd have more control over the situation .

Comment: aeid - your solution seems to be the best. I made it and it works with only few extra lines. Thaks :)

Answer (score -1):

Use keyframes to reach your desired effect, in addition to `animation-fill-mode` to keep the computed styles when the animation is finished.

```css
.object {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F00;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.object:hover {
  animation: move 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes move {
    0%   {
      transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    1% {
      transform: rotate(45deg);      
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(25px) rotate(45deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="object"></div>
```